# Require help identifying a solution to justify or align a table element without making a mess of the rest

Tags: html

I am trying to build a simple web page. I am using table elements and nearly have the page exactly how I would like it. I would like to know how if possible to align the "hideout, qty, total" block of info to top of the table, meanwhile pushing the two calculate blocks of info to align bottom? If possible to do so I would like not to have to add a ton of div elements into the code.

this is a screen shot of where I am at graphically.

http://prntscr.com/1qnyg4

this is how i would like it laid out.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtN1GjoOX2c4dHFmdDlrcy03YXMyQm02bjFOeW1fb2c&usp=sharing

```
<html>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h1>GF5F Bail Wave Calculator</h1>

    <p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign= "top">
                    <table class="dropshadow">
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center"><b> Mansion Level </b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "mansionlvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "mansionpct" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="dropshadow"><hr />
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Law Firm Level <b><mark class= "special1" >(FN)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "lawfnlvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "lawfnpct" /></td>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Law Firm Level <b><mark class= "special1" >(GV)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "lawgvlvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "lawgvpct" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Law Firm Level <b><mark class= "special1" >(BK)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "lawbklvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "lawbkpct" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Law Firm Level <b><mark class= "special1" >(PA)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "lawpalvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "lawpapct" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Law Firm Level <b><mark class= "special1" >(AC)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "lawaclvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "lawacpct" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Law Firm Level <b><mark class= "special1" >(CT)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "lawctlvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "lawctpct" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="dropshadow"><hr />
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" ><b> Total % </b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "totalpct" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <table class="dropshadow">
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" ><b> Default Jail Capacity </b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input readonly="true" type = "number" id = "jailcap" value="2000"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="dropshadow"><hr />
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Safe House <b><mark class= "special1" >(FN)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "shfnlvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "shfncap" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Safe House <b><mark class= "special1" >(GV)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "shgvlvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "shgvcap" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Safe House <b><mark class= "special1" >(BK)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "shbklvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "shbkcap" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Safe House <b><mark class= "special1" >(PA)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "shpalvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "shpacap" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Safe House <b><mark class= "special1" >(AC)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "shaclvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "shaccap" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" colspan= "2" align= "center" ><b> Safe House <b><mark class= "special1" >(CT)</mark></b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td><input type= "number" id= "shctlvl" value= "1" min= "1" max= "12" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "shctcap" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    <table class="dropshadow"><hr />
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" ><b> Total Jail Capacity </b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "totalcap" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td valign="bottom">
                    <table class="dropshadow">
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" align= "center" ><b>Hide Outs</b></td>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" align= "center" ><b>Qty</b></font></td>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" align= "center" ><b>Total</b></font></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" align= "center" ><b>Level 10</b></font></td>
                            <td><input type = "number" id = "l10qty" value="0" min="0" max="99" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly="true" type = "number" id = "l10tot" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" align= "center" ><b>Level 11</b></font></td>
                            <td><input type = "number" id = "l11qty" value="0" min="0" max="99" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly="true" type = "number" id = "l11tot" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont" headers= "name" align= "center" ><b>Level 12</b></font></td>
                            <td><input type = "number" id = "l12qty" value="0" min="0" max="99" /></td>
                            <td><input readonly="true" type = "number" id = "l12tot" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="dropshadow"><hr />
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont2" headers= "name" ><b> MAX Bailable Units </b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "bailtroops" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont2" headers= "name" ><b> Sacrificial Units Required </b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "sactroops" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="dropshadow" ><hr />
                        <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont3" headers= "name" ><b> Bailable Units </b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type = "number" id = "bailnum" value="0" min="0" /></td>
                        </tr>
                                            <tr>
                            <td class= "headfont3" headers= "name" ><b> Sacrificial Units Required </b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input readonly= "true" type= "number" id= "sacnum" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><button onclick="Calculate2()">Calculate</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're just starting out then the last thing you should be doing is learning to build web pages using tables and the `<center>` tag. That's so 1996.

Comment: Just add margin-top or margin-bottom to the elements you'd like to move. (in CSS obviously)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just learning HTML I would recommend you to look at HTML 5 and apply a layout that uses `div` elements instead of tables and use CSS instead of center.

You can use the following to center a element horizontally:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">...</div>
```

In order to align something vertically use the CSS attribute `vertical-align:top;`, you can take a look that this page for vertical alignment: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html